# changing xpath Python selenium

Tags: html, css, xpath

I'm scraping stuff off the net but i encountered an issue where i want soemtimes located in the below xpath

```
  //*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]
```

sometimes  it is located in xpath with

```
//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]
```

only the last value of the path changes. I wasn't able to use by css selector because the content is at child level within two div

please help

Comment: can you share sample input and expected output? if it's only about the final predicate being position 2 or 3 you can use `....../div[position() = 2 or position() = 3]`

Comment: @paultrmbrth thanks Paul, this however creates a list of elements(e.g. where there are 2 elements) found but I'm only interested in one of them(e.g. the information I'm trying scrap is price of an item through print(value.text). most of the time in position=2 but if there is another price its xpath become position3)....Is there a way i can pick one value based on its print(.text) result? With thanks

Comment: how do you know if you need the 2nd or 3rd? is it the last element? (in that case `[position()=last()]` would work. If not, maybe the position is not the best filter. Anything else from the content text or neighbor elements that you can filter on?
Without sample input for both cases, it's hard to give you a good answer

Comment: Hum yeah you are right sorry im new to this forum still acclimatising the site....basically fax number is what i want to grab but if there is a phone number  available the position of the fax div moves.....It is not the last element unfortunately.....i'm wondering if i can use "contain" to find the string "fax" and filter it<div data-ng-if="detail.phone" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Phone : +00 3 360 xxxx</div>                                                                                             <div data-ng-if="detail.fax" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Fax : 0508 500 xxxx</div>

Comment: then you should be able to select it with `div[starts-with(., "Fax")]` at the end

Comment: @paultrmbrth much appreciated, also would you be able to look at my code in below? It seems to exit the loop itself after a certain number of iterations(I used by pass all exceptions so not sure why the loop exit)

Comment: please ask this as another question.

Comment: now i have a new problem, the loop exit with the following exception  selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM..............However I have used waituntil element is found + two sleep timer but stil getting this error, could someone please enlighten me